# Evaluation of an integral which results in Catalan numbers

Tags: calculus

Let $\xi\le 0$, $n$ be a positive integer, and
\begin{align*}
r&=(1+2e^{2\xi}\cos 2\eta+e^{4\xi})^{1/4}, \\
\beta&=\tan^{-1}\frac{e^{2\xi}\sin 2\eta}{1+e^{2\xi}\cos 2\eta}, \\
x&=r\cos\frac{\beta}{2}, \\
y&=r\sin\frac{\beta}{2}.
\end{align*}
With a lot of trial and error experimenting with special values of $n$, I obtained the result
\begin{equation*} \begin{split}
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x\,d\eta=\pi, \\
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x\cos(2n\eta)\,d\eta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} y\sin(2n\eta)\,d\eta=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{\pi}e^{2n\xi}\Gamma(n-1/2)}{4\Gamma(n+1)}. \end{split}
\end{equation*}
The right hand side of the latter expression when multiplied by $(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n}/(\pi e^{2n\xi})$ are exactly the Catalan numbers!

So the question is: Starting from a known result from Erdelyi, or any of the numerous handbooks, is it possible to prove the above result.

Comment: Have you attempted to connect your integral with other integral representations of Catalan numbers like [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/5/3/40) ?

Comment: @Jean: Thanks for pointing me to this reference. The result I have stated above does not seem to be related to any of the integral representations in this paper.

Comment: Expanding the Gamma quotients using Gamma's recursive formulas should give you something related to the central binomial coefficients, which is known to be relevant to Catalan's numbers

Comment: It seems that, after expressing $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\xi$ and $\eta$ by trigonometric relations between $\sin z$, $\cos z$ and $\tan z$, the problem would become more understandable. Why don't you have a try? I have drafted it, you do it too.

Comment: I am sure that this problem is solvable.

Comment: For simplification, the factors $\operatorname{e}^{2\xi}$ can be regarded as a scalar and denoted by $\alpha$.

Comment: @Jog In a word, your problem should be simplified to a much concise form.

Comment: For simplicity, it is better to replace $2\eta$ by $\theta$.